# Is it possible to publish iphone apps from outside the US?

Tags: iphone, app-store, publish

I live outside the us and want to publish iphone apps in the US appstore, is it possible to do so? I heard that apps will be published at a regional appstore.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can publish apps from any country approved by Apple. Angry Birds developers are Finland based.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can publish your apps in all countries of the appstore independently of your country of residence.